# kernel density score VS score_samples python scikit

Tags: python, scikit-learn, kernel-density

I am using scikit learn and python for a few days now and more specially KernelDensity.
Once the model is fitted I would like to evaluate the probability of new points. 
The method score() is made for this but apparently doesn't work as when I put an array as entry 1 number is the output.
I use score_samples() but it is very slow.

I think that score is not working but I don't have skills to imrpove it. Please let me know if you have any idea

Answer (score 12):

score() uses score_samples() as follows:

```
return np.sum(self.score_samples(X))
```

So, that's why you should use score_samples() in your case.

Comment: exactly but shouldn't be the sum equal to 1? Why is that?

Answer (score 11):

It's a bit hard to tell, without any code, but:

We assume your points you want to evaluate are saved within array `X` and you have a kernel density estimation `kde`, so you call:

```
logprobX = kde.score_samples(X)
```

But be careful, these are logarithmic!
So you also need to do:

```
probX = np.exp(logprobX)
```

These values fit to your histogram (maybe calculated before).

The time running these lines are depending on the length of X. On my machine, it's quite fast to calculate 7500 pts.

Comment: What do you mean "eventually calculated"?  score_samples() is quite slow indeed. Should be quite parallelizable.

Comment: I don't understand why so slow, even for 2D feature space

Comment: "eventually" is a false friend in german... I edited. Sorry, that was some years ago.

The question "why it is so slow" rather is one for the developers of the module. I do not know how I could help you here.